# Expected Value of Two Random Variables

Tags: calculus, random-variables, expectation

X is a random variable with a probability density function $f(x)$, g(x,y) is a function of two variables one of them is the random variable. I have
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x,y)f(x)dx = c, \forall y \in \mathbb{R}.
\end{equation}
Can we imply anything about the relation between g(x,y) and y?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about what you mean about "the relation between $g(x,y)$ and $y$", but I am going to answer what I understand of it: *"can we infer than $g$ does not depend on $y$?"*

The answer is no: take $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$ (pdf of a standard Gaussian), and let 
$$
g(x,y) \stackrel{\rm def}{=} e^{xy-\frac{y^2}{2}}.
$$
Then $\int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x,y)f(x)dx = 1$ for all $y\in\mathbb{R}$, yet $g$ does depend on $y$ in a non-trivial fashion.

(It is also easy to build examples where $g$ does not depend on $y$, of course, for the other statement "$g$ does not necessarily depend on $y$ either.")